# Pause Vs Loops approaches

Tags: workflow, pause, loop

Lately I worked on a workflow that had to be restarted each day I used the Pause approach but I couldn't make it work, do you think Loops could handle the repetitions better than the Pause or are they same?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Won't give you a -1 but it depends on what you actually need, infinite loops vs pause? It will be easier to actually show the workflow and try to debug it instead

Comment: do something
WAIT for A date
do the samething

Comment: Why can't you just set a trigger to run the workflow when conditions are met?

Comment: Could be a duplicate: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/205572/65896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to accomplish.  If you are waiting for an event like a change to a column or a task completion, I would use the loop because it can help you catch things like if someone assigned to a task rejects the task, the loop can be used to catch that and reassign it.  Using a pause feature would not let you do that and would just proceed to the next step.  The loop is more flexible.

I use pauses for simple things that I know the interval and I don't need to catch any variances like sending a reminder after two weeks.

Hope it helps.